# Why Camera is not starting when running my Android application with update version?

Tags: android, camera

I have created an android application with 2.1 version. When I am starting my application with  update version like 2.2 or more updated, the camera is showing Force Close error or Camera is starting but it becoming hang. My code is given be

```
public class CameraCapture extends MenuActivitySpecific {

    protected ImageView image;
    protected String _path;
    File sdImageMainDirectory;
    private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
    protected boolean _taken = true;
    private Uri imageUri;
    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    private Dialog dialog;
    private Handler imageUploadhandler, databaseHandler;
    DBAdapter db;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.cameracapturedimage);
        setLanguage(CameraCapture.this,"ja_JP");
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        startCameraActivity2();
        imageUploadhandler = new Handler();
        databaseHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menucapturedimage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.backToHome:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.save:
            upload();
            return true;
        case R.id.retakePicture:
            startCameraActivity2();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageToLoad) {
        Log.d("Message 1 ", "setting language");
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); //e.g "sv"

        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Log.d("Message 3: ", locale+" Language set");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        try{
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Picture taken!!!");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cameraImage);
                image.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CameraCapture.this, Home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                imageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(imageUri);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cameraImage);
                image.setImageURI(imageUri);

            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CameraCapture.this, Home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error: 169 CameraCapture: ", e+" ");
        }
    }

    protected void startCameraActivity2() {

        try {

            if (Constants.fromGallery) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");

                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        GALLERY_REQUEST);
            } else {
                Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Starting camera on the phone...");
                String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaColumns.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION,
                        "Image capture by camera");
                values.put(MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: 174 CameraCapture: ", e + "");

        }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        try{
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            Log.e("Error: 219 CameraCapture: ", e+"");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void upload() {
        try {
            boolean check = Utility.isNetworkAvailable(CameraCapture.this);
            // boolean check1 =isOnline();
            if (check) {


                String abc = imageUri.toString();

                Log.e("Image URI String ", abc);

                String newtime = Utility.getdate();
                String accesskey = Utility.MD5_Hash(Constants.email + newtime
                        + "moko");
                Constants.ACCESS_KEY = accesskey;
                Constants.proc_date = newtime;
                imageUploadhandler.postDelayed(runImageUpload, 500);
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CameraCapture.this, "",
                        "しばらくお待ちください", true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
            } else {

                databaseHandler.postDelayed(runDatabaseImageSave, 500);
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CameraCapture.this, "",
                        "しばらくお待ちください", true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(this, e + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CameraCapture.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            _taken = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(CameraCapture.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    public static void StoreImage(Context mContext, Uri imageLoc, File imageDir) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {

            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(), imageLoc);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageDir);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            Log.e("file dir", imageDir.toString());

            bm.recycle();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private final Runnable runImageUpload = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            ResponseFromServer response = Utility.upload(imageUri,
                    CameraCapture.this);

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            Log.i("Image Uploading status:", response.getStatus()+"");
            if (response != null) {


                if (response.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "画像を保存しました。",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(CameraCapture.this,AllProductActivityNew.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraCapture.this)
                        .setTitle("エラー")
                        .setMessage("ファイル送信に失敗しました。")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    }
                                }).show();
                return;

            }

        }
    };

    private final Runnable runDatabaseImageSave = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        imageUri);

                byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
                db.open();
                String stringUri = imageUri.toString();
                String userMail = Constants.email;
                Log.e("Email: ", userMail + "");
                boolean feedback = db.InsertImage(inputData, stringUri,
                        userMail, 1);

                db.close();

                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                if (feedback) {
                    Toast.makeText(CameraCapture.this, "画像を保存しました。",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraCapture.this)
                            .setTitle("エラー")
                            .setMessage("ファイル送信に失敗しました。")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        }
                                    }).show();
                    return;

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error to upload Image to database: ", e + "");
            }

        }
    };

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue where when clicking to click a picture,the camera hung up.Couldn't resolve it despite repeated attempts.

Comment: How to solve this problem? Anybody help me?